# Ansible run remote exe file

Tags: windows, ansible, winrm

How to execute an exe file on a remote Windows machine with Ansible? I used raw, script and command modules, but the thing is, the exe file is running in a different session, and cannot see the application UI in the desktop of the remote machine.

2nd issue is the ansible playbook doesn't move forward after the exe execution.

Can we run the exe in the active desktop session?

Comment: I think those are two different questions. Your first question is not necessarily related to Ansible. It seems to me you want to know how to execute an application over ssh for an active Windows session? You might get better/faster answers if you ask that question again without the Ansible reference. For the 2nd question, what exactly is the issue? Is the task hanging or is an error thrown? How exactly do you call the exe?

Comment: Thank you Daniel

I agree with you, this is not just Ansible, but what I wanted to know is, can we initiate a stable WinRM session with Ansible? I cannot see we can achieve this with raw, command and script modules. Is there any other way to initiate a session to do 

1. Create a session
2. Generate credentials
3. Execute the exe file as a service

Regarding the 2nd issue, yes it hangs as long as the remote exe is running.

I have tried calling the exe with following methods

1. Start-process <path>/file.exe
2. start path/file.exe
3. created local/remote powershell scripts to do the same.

Comment: I see, so the program keeps running. You will have to run the process in the background then. I think on Windows a background process can be started like this: `START /B C:\path\to\your.exe`. I have no idea regarding the WinRM session though.

Comment: I have resolved the issue with psexec, it is a really useful tool and I could address both issues with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could resolve these issues with psexec.

```
#Creating the credential for the invoke-command.
$strScriptUser = "COMPUTERNAME\USer"
$strPass = "PASSWORD"
$PSS = ConvertTo-SecureString $strPass -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = new-object system.management.automation.PSCredential $strScriptUser,$PSS

#Invoke-Command to call the psexec to start the application.

invoke-command -Computer "." -Scriptblock {
c:\AnsibleTest\ps\psexec.exe -accepteula  -d -h -i 1 -u COMPUTERNAME\USER -p PASSWORD PATH_TO_THE_EXE\PROGRAM.EXE
}  -Credential $cred
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the win_psexec module for this.

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/win_psexec_module.html